# SQL Insert From PowerQuery

Tags: list, function, multiple-columns, powerquery

I need to convert a query on excel to a Insert on SQL, I wont to create a function  that will work on any query, and Invoke it, so he need to be quite reusable.

```
let
    SQL = (TableX as table) => let
        // Get Columns Name abd use on the columns INSERT
        SOURCE = TableX,
        Names = Table.ColumnNames(SOURCE),
        ListN = Table.FromList(Names),
        TransposeN = Table.Transpose(ListN),
        CombineN = Table.CombineColumns(TransposeN,Table.ColumnNames(TransposeN),Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"M"),
        ColunmsAsText = List.Single(CombineN[M]),
        // ColumnsasText is all the Columns Name
        // This part I cant do I need to format all columns acording to the type and Combine They
        COLUNMS = (ListN as text) => let
            TYPE = some.function.to.get.type(SOURCE[ListN]),
            if TYPE = date then FIELDS = FIELDS & "'" & Date.ToText([ListN], "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'," else
            if TYPE = text then FIELDS = FIELDS & "'" & [ListN] & "'," else
            if TYPE = number then FIELDS = FIELDS & [ListN] & "," else FIELDS = FIELDS & "#error,"
   in
        FIELDS
        INSERT = "INSERT INTO " & "TABLENAME" & " (" & ColunmsAsText & ") VALUES (" & FIELDS & ");",
        NEWCOLUMNADD = Table.AddColumn(SOURCE, "SQL", each INSERT)
in
    NEWCOLUMNADD
in
    SQL
```

The problem is the FIELDS variable where, I need to compose a string of all columns, and the function "some.function.to.get.type", and the output 'll be something like this, for each row:

```
 INSERT INTO (Column_name1, Column_name2, Column_name3) value (15, '2017-05-20', 'Text hear');
```

Tanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You want [`Value.Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260827.aspx)

```
Value.Type("abc") = type text
```